# Method 'frames' of object 'JScriptTypeInfo' failed

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel, frames, comexception

I am working on automation of internet explorer 9 through excel VBA, it throws an error when I reach on the last line below:

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "https://example.com/Main.asp"

'delay till readystate is complete

Set doc = ie.document
Set doc1 = doc.frames(2).document 'here comes the error
```

can anyone please help?

Comment: Remove excessive `Set ie = New InternetExplorer`, add `Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop` after `.navigate`. Try to find necessary frame manually in webpage content using F12.

Comment: There are indeed frames on the webpage. I inspected with **F12**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i Have face the same issue and it got resolved

This will work for IE 10+

Set doc = ie.document.frames

Set doc1 = doc.frames(2)

For the script element, readyState is no longer supported. Starting with Internet Explorer 11, use onload

[IE 11 has different ways to access attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534359(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with some Excel VBA code after migrating to IE11. This is what I had to do to fix it:

old code which worked in IE8 but threw the error in IE11

```
Set objCollection = IE.Document.frames(0).Document.getElementsByTagName("span")
```

new code which works in IE11
(I had to add a reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library under tools/references)

```
Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim htmlWindow As MSHTML.HTMLWindow2
Set htmlDoc = IE.Document
Set htmlWindow = htmlDoc.frames(0)
Set objCollection = htmlWindow.Document.getElementsByTagName("span")
```

Comment: Thank you, is this code working? It gives an "access denied" error