# scraping a tab within a website using vba

Tags: javascript, html, vba

I'm trying to click on a tab in a website that is activated with what appears to be onmouse events. Here is a snippet of the html:

```
<frame name ="nav">
<body><div id="tab2flyover0" 
onmouseover="document.getElementById('tab2flyover0DivShim').style.width = document.getElementById('tab2flyover0').offsetWidth;
onmouseout="document.getElementById('tab2flyover0').style.visibility='hidden';document.getElementById('tab2flyover0DivShim')
onmouseover="document.getElementById('tab2_tab2Cell0')onmouseout="document.getElementById('tab2_tab2Cell0')
onclick="parent.frames[0].changeTopTabs('tab2TableDetail') parent.frames[0].changeContentFrame('/MISO/DART/selectDARTParticipant.do');">    
<p id="tab2_tab2flyover0text0" style="color: rgb(255, 153, 0);">Select Party</p>
```

The last row of code tag "p" is where it takes me when I "inspect element".

Below is a snippet of my vba code so far:

```
Sub scrape()
Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.IHTMLDocument 'Document object
Dim eleColtr As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection 'Element collection for tr tags
Dim eleColtd As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection 'Element collection for td tags
Dim eleRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement 'Row elements
Dim eleCol As MSHTML.IHTMLElement 'Column elements
Dim ieURL As String 'URL

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True   
With ie
.
Shell "wscript.exe ""C:\Users\Ar\Desktop\vbscript.vbs"""
        Do Until .readyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop
Set htmldoc = ie.document
Set dar = htmldoc.frames("nav").document.getElementById("tab2_tab2flyover0text0")
dar.Click
Do Until .readyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
.document.forms(0).submit
End With
End Sub
```

The error I'm getting says: "Method 'frames' of object JScriptTypeInfo' failed".

I've never dealt with onmouse events before so maybe this is where i'm having issues?

Comment: Needs a bit more code...

Comment: Tim, I have included all the vba code, Thanks!

Comment: The error comes on the "Set dar" line.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do again? I think the headline of the question needs work.

Comment: I'm basically just trying to click a tab within a website. The tab pulls up a menu when hovering over it. So I need to click an item from the menu that is pulled up after hovering over the tab. I'm having trouble clicking on the menu that is pulled up after hovering over a tab.

Answer (score 0):

The tag with the onclick event is the tag

```
<div id="tab2flyover0">
```

You are selecting the following tag and clicking:

```
<p id="tab2_tab2flyover0text0" style="color: rgb(255, 153, 0);">Select Party</p>
```

I would change the code to the following and try again, I have done something similar just recently and have had no issues. (Using Powershell not VBA)

```
Set dar = htmldoc.frames("nav").document.getElementById("tab2flyover0")
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting the same error when using tab2flyover0: "Method 'frames' of object JScriptTypeInfo' failed". I selected the p tag initially because that is where the inspect element highlights when I click the menu. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Try this instead
Set dar = htmldoc.getElementById("tab2flyover0")

Comment: It gave me a "Type Mismatch" error.. any idea why that would be?

Comment: Hard to say without being able to debug myself. One thing I did notice when doing this in Powershell is I had to run powershell as administrator. Looking into it a bit more, as you have a frame I think you had it correct referencing the frames document. Perhaps I should look for a site with frames to test...

Comment: Ok let me know if you have any further suggestions, appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Proving difficult to find a site that also uses frames. But I would break the code up a bit more to debug. For example.
Add decleration of frame document.

```
Dim frameDoc As MSHTML.IHTMLDocument
```

Then break up the line:

```
Set dar = htmldoc.frames("nav").document.getElementById("tab2flyover0")
```

Into

```
Set frameDoc = htmldoc.frames("nav").document
Set Dar = frameDoc.getElementById("tab2flyover0")
```

Also you have not declared the type for dar.
Then check back what line of code the error is occurring on.

Comment: correction on my last comment, the error actually says: "Method 'frames' of object'JScriptTypeInfo' failed".

Comment: Checkout this, looks like you need to declare the frame as MSHTML.htmlwindows2 then once that second window is set you should be able to get the data from it you need. I cant test because dont have a site with frames and id tags to test with:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347286/method-frames-of-object-jscripttypeinfo-failed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347286/method-frames-of-object-jscripttypeinfo-failed